# How to prevent article titles to become links

Tags: views, 8

I am making a website in Drupal 8. I made a new content type 'Slide' and a view called 'Presentation' that shows all slides as a blog page. I enabled the pager and set it to 1 item per page. This results in a nice slide show. See screenshot ('presentatie' is Dutch for 'presentation'):

[image: Screenshot view 'Presentatie']

The slides are small articles, containing text content and an image. They are shown by the Presentation view as full content, but their titles are still shown as links to the full article (slide) content. I don't want this linking, because by going to the full article, you leave the presentation page with pager for navigating through the slides. See screenshot of result on site below:

[image]

I am pretty new to Drupal and I can not find where or how to switch this off. Could anyone tell me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the view **Presentation**, under **FORMAT** change **Show: Content** into **Show: Fields**.

Then under **FIELDS** add the desired fields, in my case:

- **Content: Title**
- **Content: Body**
- **Content: Image**

To get the correct formatting and css styling by my theme:

- Under **FORMAT** open **Format: Settings**, set **Row class** to "node".
- Under **FIELDS** open **Content: Title**, under **STYLE SETTINGS** check **Customize field HTML** and set **HTML element** to "H2".
- Under **FIELDS** open **Content: Body**, under **STYLE SETTINGS** check **Customize field HTML** and set **HTML element** to "DIV".

Answer (score 1):

To remove link from Title, what you have to do is click on the title field in views, and there is a checkbox `Link to the Content`. To unlink this, you have to uncheck this field. I am attaching a screenshot to it :

[image]

Comment: Hi, thanks for the try. What you are showing, is how to remove the links from the article/page titles in the admin view 'Content'. That's not what I meant. I edited my question, adding a screenshot and making it more specific.

Comment: @Herman you could change the `Show: Content` to `Show: Fields` then add the body field and any other field you need.

Comment: @NoSssweat Yesss... thank you so much, that does the job quite well! I actually tried `Show: Fields`, but couldn't find the body field to add it (was looking for content). I will create an answer to my question from this, as soon as I have figured out how to get the correct html code around the fields (title in `<h2>`).

Comment: @Herman click on title field and then under style settings select h2

Comment: @NoSssweat O, perfect! Lot of options I see. Thanks again! I am exploring Drupal since three days now (I have been using Joomla for some years) and Drupal is slowly gaining more and more appreciation...

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this in views when using rendered nodes. In fact, you can't do it in the UI with just core. This is hardcoded in the node template, unfortunately.

You have to either provide a node template for that node type and view mode (see https://www.drupal.org/node/2354645) and then remove the link tag around the title, or use a module like [Display Suite](https://www.drupal.org/project/ds)

Comment: Display suite explanation is here: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/76013/how-to-show-titles-as-plain-text-on-rendered-entity-reference

Comment: @Neograph734 Thanks for effort, but it turned out to be possible very well. See answer, based on NoSssweat's comments.

Comment: @Herman Yes, note how I said "when using rendered nodes". You can do it with fields, and if that works for you great. That has other limitations (like, when you actually want to customize a template, I find it much harder to do with views fields) and it's not as performant as each field is rendered on its own. shouldn't make a huge difference now that views output is also cached.